# Is there a limit for System.IO.FileShare?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file-io

I want to build my own flat file database. Here is how I access the flat file database

```
Dim fs As New System.IO.FileStream("C:\MyDb.txt", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.Read)
Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(fs)
```

Is there a limit imposed by .Net for the usage of  `System.IO.FileShare.Read`, `System.IO.FileShare.Write` and `System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite` when dealing with a file?

I mean is that .Net capable to support thousands of users using **file stream** and **stream reader** objects with `System.IO.FileShare.Read` to access a single file concurrently?

Comment: Hi, I would expect if there is a limit is more about the underlying windows APIs which most likely .NET wraps...

Comment: No limits beyond kernel pool memory used up by all these I/O requests.  Having thousands of apps read from a file that you write to is, well, courageous.  There's no way to synchronize, these apps are going to read partially written lines of text.  This is why servers exist, SQL Server is highly preferrable, a text file is not a dbase.

Comment: Hans: Synchronizing access to files is why file locking was invented.

Comment: I would suggest adding a data access tier to do the file reading and writing and everything talking to this tier. That way you only have one process reading or writing to the file and you can handle multiple connections to you data tier.

Comment: Tell me your .Net & windows version, I will perform a real test for you

Comment: There is no limit imposed by .Net. Only by the underling operating system. Imagine you weren't using .Net at all but just had many users trying to access a file on a file share, the limitations would be the same. If the file is concurrently updated, the limitations will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the exact limit imposed by .NET/windows, so I have created a real test for you. I ran the following test code for few minutes and I found that up to **635908** counts of `system.io.fileshare` usage, it still functional, i.e. you can still read the flat database file's content.

Here is the code (it is a winform application, .Net 4):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim filepath As String = "c:\database.txt"

        Dim filestream As System.IO.FileStream

        Dim count As Int32

        For count = 0 To System.Int32.MaxValue
            filestream = New System.IO.FileStream(filepath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.Read)
            AppendLog(count, filestream.ReadByte)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private LogFilepath As String = "C:\LogInfo.txt"
    Private Enter As String = Chr(13) & Chr(10)
    Private Space As String = " "

    Private Sub AppendLog(ByVal Sequence As Int32, ByVal info As Byte)
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(LogFilepath, Enter & Sequence & Space & CStr(info))
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 4):

If you try to open a file with conflicting access and share permissions it won't work. 
But if this is a custom database, why would you need more than one file handle open? 
Your custom database software should manage the open handles (having 1 per file). 
As for your specific question, there's no set limit, but subsequent opens of the file need to follow the rules for access and sharing permissions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The `FileShare` member means that other files can also open the file. This does **not** guarantee that data will be synchronised in any way - it simply means that multiple programs can now read (since that's what you set - `FileShare.Read`) from that file while you have it open.

If you use `ReadWrite`, then multiple programs can read from and write to the file. Again, you will **not** be notified of any changes. If multiple programs are writing to the same file at the same time as a stream, the data will be mixed together and you'll get a corrupt file. (Corrupt meaning that neither you nor the other program will be able to decompile it because your data is intertwined with your friends' application).

There are no unreasonable limitations to the number of concurrent programs reading a file.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple objects can access a single file, however Disk on which the files is saved maintains read cache buffer for each object / process and the cache would multiply with number of objects accessing the file.
The performance depends on the amount of bytes required to maintain cache per objects and total capacity of cache memory.

If file is modified when reading  operation is performed then asynchronous reads should be used. however if a process terminates with part of a file locked or closes a file that has outstanding locks, the behavior is undefined.

I would recommend to explicitly destroy the stream objects when not required.

Answer (score 0):

You should have only one `FileStream` for writing to the file, and limit its use to one thread at a time using the usual locking mechanisms. The usual model for DBMS software is to have a concurrent queue of write operations and have a write thread that flushes them. In cases where you need the source of the write operation to await its completion, you can use an async model (BeginWrite/EndWrite).

A `Semaphore` may be precisely what you need for reading, since it allows a maximum number of threads to have access to it at any point in time. You can use it to limit the disk thrashing that would occur for an unlimited number of simultaneous random reads.

However, you should ALWAYS keep a cache of the "hottest" data in memory to reduce load. Without it, your disk will just not be fast enough to keep up.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file normally means that it is opened exclusively by you and no other process can access it, unless you tell Windows you want to share it.

Setting FileShare.Read/Write means, that you grant other processes the right to read or write the file while you have it open.

I restate: You grant other processes the right to read and/or write to your file. Nothing more, nothing less.

Let's imagine the file-sharing bits as a door:

- None means, the door is closed and locked.
- Read means, you can only go one way.
- Write means, you can only go the other way.

So, what's the limit of a door?